# Programmatically LZMA decompressing a static LZMA-compressed file

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, lzma

I'm LZMA-decompressing a resource file which I earlier compressed using `lzma e <infile> <outfile> -lc0 -lp2` from the terminal and imported to my project. However when applied to this file `LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf` returns `1` in the first iteration, i.e. LZMA data error. (Also by which time `inLen` is always `5`, `outLen` is `0`.)

Why is that?

My code reads:

```
SRes static decompress(FILE *inFile, FILE *outFile)
{
  // Position the inFile pointer at the start.
  fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

  // Read in LZMA properties (5 bytes) and uncompressed size (8 bytes, little-endian) to header.
  char unsigned header[LZMA_PROPS_SIZE+8];
  fgets(header, sizeof(header), inFile);
  CLzmaDec state;
  LzmaDec_Construct(&state);
  SRes res = LzmaDec_Allocate(&state, header, LZMA_PROPS_SIZE, &SzAllocForLzma);

  if (res != SZ_OK) {
    // Free all allocated structures.
    LzmaDec_Free(&state, &SzAllocForLzma);
    return res;
  }

  char unsigned inBuf[IN_BUF_SIZE];
  char unsigned outBuf[OUT_BUF_SIZE];
  LzmaDec_Init(&state);

  ELzmaStatus status;
  long unsigned outLen = sizeof(outBuf);
  long unsigned inLen = sizeof(inBuf);
  long unsigned inPos = ftell(inFile);

  while (fgets(inBuf, sizeof(inBuf), inFile) != NULL) {
    inLen = MIN(sizeof(inBuf), MAX(ftell(inFile)-inPos, 0));
    outLen = sizeof(outBuf);

    SRes res = LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(&state,
                                   outBuf,
                                   &outLen,
                                   inBuf,
                                   &inLen,
                                   LZMA_FINISH_ANY,
                                   &status);
// continues...
```

Comment: Crystal ball foggy.  Try debugging and see where it goes wrong.  But in all seriousness, this is a very difficult issue to try and internet debug.  Perhaps you're missing or added a header to the data?  Perhaps you are passing in garbage?  Perhaps you've accidently stomped some of its data.  Debugging might point you in the right direction, but I wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old post to be replying to, however I ran into this same problem.

The issue is that the header is NOT supposed to be a part of the data you are decompressing. The solution is to start at **sizeof(header)** instead of **0**, when reading the data, and don't forget to also adjust it's total length by **sizeof(header)** as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the input is not a 7zArchive? That would need calls to SzArEx_Open and SzArEx_Extract.